# how to add shortcode widget at end of main blog page

Tags: shortcode

not able to add subscribe to newsletter shortcode at end of blog page. want to add after pagination and before footer. anybody know how to add?
the page i am working on [Website](https://www.cloudaeon.co.uk/category/blog/)

Comment: have you looked at `do_shortcode` ? it lets you run a shortcode from PHP. You could add it at the end of your main index.php.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `do_shortcode` as mozboz suggested.
But I think that using the single.php file is a better way of doing it.
The template you should use will depend on how your theme is structured, but if the element is supposed to always display after a post then editing the main template is the best way to do it.

Comment: After adding the `<?php echo do_shortcode('[name_of_shortcode]'); ?>` code into `single-blog.php` getting error **Website Experiencing technical difficulties**

Comment: Would you be able to specify if use kept the square brackets around `('[name_of_shortcode]')` or if you just used `('name_of_shortcode')` in your final code?

Comment: Getting a WordPress PHP error could also be caused by other factors. I would suggest checking the `error.log` file to see what the actual issue might be. Unfortunetely WP doesn't like to be specific about its error codes.